# vkGetInstanceProcAddress fails on debug reports extension

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am attempting to enable debug reporting as shown in: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers,

But the following function always fails:

```
VkResult CreateDebugReportCallbackEXT(
    VkInstance instance, 
    const VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT* pCreateInfo, 
    const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, 
    VkDebugReportCallbackEXT* pCallback
) 
{
    auto func = (PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT");
    if (func != nullptr) {
        return func(instance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pCallback);
    }
    else {
        return VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
}
```

func always ends up a null pointer, which as the code says, indicates the extension isn't present.

The code which calls the above function is:

```
void setDebugCallBack()
{
    if (!enableValidationLayers) return;
    VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT createInfo = {};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CALLBACK_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
    createInfo.flags = VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT;
    createInfo.pfnCallback = debugCallback;
    VkResult result = CreateDebugReportCallbackEXT(instance, &createInfo, nullptr, &callback);
    if (result != VK_SUCCESS) 
{
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to set up debug callback!: Extension not present");
    }
}
```

I create the instance like so:

```
void createInstance()
{
    if (enableValidationLayers && !checkValidationLayerSupport()) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("validation layers requested, but not available!");
    }
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

    if (enableValidationLayers) {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
        createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();
    }
    else {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    }

    unsigned int glfwExtensionCount = 0;
    const char** glfwExtensions;

    glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

    createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionCount;
    createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;

    createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create instance!");
    }

    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> extensions(extensionCount);
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, extensions.data());
    std::cout << "available extensions:" << std::endl;

    for (const auto& extension : extensions)
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << extension.extensionName << std::endl;
    }

    auto ext = getRequiredExtensions();
    createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(ext.size());
    createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = ext.data();
}
```

And the code which adds the extension name is as follows:

```
std::vector<const char*> getRequiredExtensions() 
{
    std::vector<const char*> extensions;

    unsigned int glfwExtensionCount = 0;
    const char** glfwExtensions;
    glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < glfwExtensionCount; i++) 
    {
        extensions.push_back(glfwExtensions[i]);
    }

    if (enableValidationLayers) 
    {
        extensions.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME);
    }

    return extensions;
}
```

Is this a driver/hardware issue, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: when creating the instance did you request the extension?

Comment: I believe so, though I may not have done it correctly. I'll update the question with more code.

Comment: Aah I see what I did wrong! I am calling getRequiredExtensions after instance creation, which means it was never requested.

Answer (score 2):

I see my error:

I had to change `createInstance` to:

```
void createInstance()
{
    if (enableValidationLayers && !checkValidationLayerSupport()) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("validation layers requested, but not available!");
    }
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

    if (enableValidationLayers) {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
        createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();
    }
    else {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    }
    //Removed glfw extension calls and data, as already requested in getRequiredExtensions()
    auto extensions = getRequiredExtensions();
    createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
    createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();

    createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create instance!");
    }

    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> extensions(extensionCount);
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, extensions.data());
    std::cout << "available extensions:" << std::endl;

    for (const auto& extension : extensions)
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << extension.extensionName << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I had to replace the glwf extension calls with the new extension request code, rather than append the function, and make sure the call was prior to instance creation. This ensured that the extension was properly requested and enabled.